# SQL Server : loading flat file from Informix

Tags: sql-server, loading

How can I load my text file into a SQL Server database if my flat file doesn't contain any row delimiter?

I tried using `openrowset`, but it only put the data in 1 column..

Also tried generating format

```
bcp dbname.owner.tablename format nul -c -f tablename-c.fmt -T
```

but the output is network related or instance specific error.

And I also can't find the `AlwaysCheckForRowDelimiters` property.

Are there any other options for loading these types of data?

Text file with only column delimiter, and  not fixed length. This is a unload file from an Informix database.

Comment: What syntax do you use in Informix to create the file? The `UNLOAD` statement does have a `DELIMITER` clause after all.

Comment: Delimiter in informix is just for column delimiter, im not sure if there's delimiter for row?